# canvas.toDataURL fails in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm working in a PHP/jQuery environment and running into an issue that I could use a little guidance or suggestions with.

We have some jQuery code that we are attempting to use to export image data from an HTML5 canvas as PNG data that we will be using to feed PHP's imagecreatefrompng() function so that we can save the image as a file. The way we're trying to do it works in FF & Chrome, but IE9 seems to be not doing so well. (go figure)

The code we have is as follows;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function invertCase(inString) {
    var outString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < inString.length; ++i) {
      var ch = inString.charAt(i);
      outString += (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ? ch.toLowerCase() : ch.toUpperCase();
    }
    return outString;
  }

  $("#sig-canvas").payjunctionSigCap();
  $("#draw-sig").click(function() {
    var sigVal = $("#signature").val();
    if(/^\}[a-z]{8}/m.test(sigVal)) {
      sigVal = invertCase(sigVal);
    }

    $("#sig-canvas").payjunctionSigCap("showScriptel", sigVal);
      return false;
    });

    $("#clear-sig").click(function() {
      $("#sig-canvas").payjunctionSigCap("clear");
      $("#signature").val("");
      return false;
    });

    $("#signed").click(function() {
      var canvas1 = $("#sig-canvas-canvas");

      $("#data").val( canvas1.toDataURL("image/png") );
    });
});
```

Here's what I get when the resulting data ends up back in PHP's lap.

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/var/www/vhosts/<siteroot>/eSignatures/00Qd000000GzpsLEAR.png' is not a valid PNG file in /var/www/vhosts/<siteroot>/SigPad.php on line 24

Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/<siteroot>/SigPad.php on line 26

Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/<siteroot>/SigPad.php on line 27
```

Is there something that IE9 is doing to the data that's screwing it up?
Also, is there a way to get IE to show me the data that is being generated like console.log(imgData)?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are running IE9 in compatibility mode? This is found under developer tools, if it currently is try turning it off.

Comment: what is the content of /var/www/vhosts/<siteroot>/eSignatures/00Qd000000GzpsLEAR.png ?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I checked. It's not in compat mode and I even forced the document mode to "IE9 Standards" in the meta tag.

Comment: @akonsu - It's a 0 byte file because PHP is never able to make the file to begin with. Hence the errors I posted.

Comment: what is the return value of canvas1.toDataURL in the line $("#data").val( canvas1.toDataURL("image/png") ); besides, canvas1 is not a DOM object, it is a jQuery object, no?

Comment: Do jQuery objects have a `toDataURL` method? My jsfiddle says no: http://jsfiddle.net/5v7MA/1. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Okay...this makes no sense whatsoever. If I use conventional javascript to do this, it works. But if I use jQuery, it throws the error apsillers is referring to.
JS: document.getElementById('data').value = document.getElementById('sig-canvas-canvas').toDataURL("image/png");